# Passing a JavaScript array to IEnumerable gives null values

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a huge amount of trouble passing a Javascript array to my controller in MVC 3. I keep getting null values and feel like I have tried every way of passing the array. Below is the JavaScript, the relevant view models for the `Questions` and the controller signature. I'd appreciate any help. I'm not getting any errors in my JavaScript and I think i must be missing something fundamental.

The values for `id` and `response-id` are being received correctly at the controller.

**javascript**

```
$("#form-submit-scores").submit(function () {

        var question = [],
        var item = [],

        $('.questionRow').each(function (index) {
            question[index] = new Array();
            var fullQuestionId = $(this).attr('id');
            var fullQuestionParts = fullQuestionId.split('-');
            question[index].QuestionId = fullQuestionParts[fullQuestionParts.length - 1];
            question[index].QuestionScore = $('.scoreBoard').val();
        });

        $('.itemRow').each(function (index) {
            item[index] = new Array();
            item[index].ItemId = $(this).attr('id');
            item[index].ItemScore = $('.scoreBoard').val();
        });

        var url = "/ctr/SaveResponse",
            data = {
                Id: $('#id').val(),
                ResponseId: $('#response-id').val(),
                Questions: question,
                Items : item
            },

        if (isSubmitScores) {
            url = "/ctr/SubmitResponse"
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'Post',
            data: data,
            traditional:true,
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                if (!result.Success) {

....
....
....
```

**viewmodels**

```
public class SubmitResponseViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ResponseId { get; set; }
        IEnumerable<SubmitResponseScoresQuestionViewModel> Questions {get;set;}
        IEnumerable<SubmitResponseScoresItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
    }



public class SubmitResponseScoresQuestionViewModel
    {
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public decimal? QuestionScore { get; set; }
    }
```

**controller signature**

```
public JsonResult SubmitResponseScores(SubmitResponseScoresViewModel model)
```

So as I said above, my model now contains the correct values for `Id` and `response-id` but null values for `Questions` and `Items`. I have confirmed that my `data` is being populated in the AJAX call so i'm thinking that I'm not providing the data in the appropriate format for the controller.

**EDIT:1**

Chrome JS Debugger: AJAX Data object

```
  JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
"{
  "Id": "1027",
  "ResponseId": "26",
  "Questions": [
    {
      "QuestionId": "7",
      "QuestionScore": "0"
    },
    {
      "QuestionId": "2",
      "QuestionScore": "0"
    },
    {
      "QuestionId": "1",
      "QuestionScore": "0"
    }
  ],
  "Items": [
    {
      "ItemId": "434",
      "ItemScore": "0"
    }
  ]
}"
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see you ever touching `Questions` and `Items` in your JS. What happens if you use `question` and `item` instead of `Questions` and `Items`

Comment: Apologies, left something out, i'll edit now

Comment: I'm not sure that jQuery will actually convert the data to JSON when you specify `contentType: "application/json"`. Have you checked the data being transmitted?

Comment: @Barmar I have confirmed that the `id` and `response-id` are being transmitted to the controller correctly with and without `contentType: "application/json`. It's the `IEnumerable` values that has me stumped. No matter what I do i get nothing but Null values

Comment: That's the part I wanted you to check. Use a packet capture to see if they're being converted to JSON. You may need to use `JSON.stringify()` in the Javascript.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by using a packet capture but using `JSON.stringify()` on my data object sets my `id` and `response-id` = 0 and the others are still null. I inspected the data object in Chrome and will append the results to my original post

Comment: Why are you making each array element a `new Array()`? You're making an array of arrays. If you want to create a new array object to set properties on, you could just do `item[index] = {};` and then `item[index].ItemId = ...`.

Comment: If you want a neater "dump" of your `data` object, open the console in your debugger and run this: `JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)`.

Comment: @BernhardHofmann I have changed the code as per your advice above regarding creating a new object instead of a new array but still with the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to serialize your array to JSON using JSON.stringify
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

1) install Json.net in Nuget to include the JsonFilter notation

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

2) place a Json Filter annotation on your action method

```
[JsonFilter(Param = "attributes", JsonDataType = typeof(AttributeViewModel[]))]
  JsonResult SubmitResponseScores(SubmitResponseScoresViewModel model)
```

3) In your ajax call:

```
    data:  JSON.stringify(data),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your collections for Questions and Items need to be public else they will not be bound to the model on post-back