# Controller recieving empty data from Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send a collection from a view to a controller, using ajax. First I complete the data in a javascript array, and then I try to pass it to the server:

```
    var funciones = $("#funcionesUsuario").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
    var func = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < funciones.length; i++) {
        func.push({
            "Estado": 1,
            "FechaAlta": null,
            "UsuarioAlta": null,
            "FechaModificacion": null,
            "UsuarioModificacion": null,
            "BitConcilia": funciones[i].BitConcilia,
            "BitLectura": funciones[i].BitLectura,
            "BitSupervisa": funciones[i].BitSupervisa,
            "ConciliacionId": funciones[i].ConciliacionId,
            "UsuarioId": funciones[i].UsuarioId
        })
    }

    $.post(url, { funcionesUsuario: func })
        .done(function (data) {
        alert("good job");
    });
```

Then, since I'm sending data for 2 objects, my parameter is a IEnumerable of said object:

```
public void ActualizarFuncionesUsuario(IEnumerable<FuncionUsuario> funcionesUsuario)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

My problem is that the controller receives 2 objects, as I can see in the funcionesUsuario.count, but they are both empty.

I tried sending int, bool and other types of variables with success, so I suspect I'm doing something wrong regarding data binding.

Below I attached pictures of what I'm sending and what I'm receiving in the other side.

[image: Picture of the js function]
[image: Picture of the controller]

This is the `FuncionUsuario` model: `

```
public class FuncionUsuario : AuditableEntity { 
    public int ConciliacionId { get; set; } 
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; } 
    public bool BitLectura { get; set; } 
    public bool BitConcilia { get; set; } 
    public bool BitSupervisa { get; set; } 
    public virtual Conciliacion Conciliacion { get; set; } 
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Global), Name = "Descripcion")] 
    [NotMapped] 
    public string Descripcion { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: What does your `FuncionUsuario` model schema look like?

Comment: This is not a definitive answer, but there are a couple of similar questions where stringifying the data / providing an appropriate `contentType` did the trick. I would definitely try specifying `contentType` first, and then follow that up with stringifying only if necessary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101896/mvc-3-ajax-post-list-filled-with-objects-but-objects-properties-are-empty, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691977/passing-a-javascript-array-to-ienumerable-gives-null-values

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for the edit! I was going to do that but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first construct you array as java script objects

```
var funciones = $("#funcionesUsuario").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
var func = [];

for (var i = 0; i < funciones.length; i++) {
    func.push({
        Estado: 1,
        FechaAlta: null,
        UsuarioAlta: null,
        FechaModificacion: null,
        UsuarioModificacion: null,
        BitConcilia: funciones[i].BitConcilia,
        BitLectura: funciones[i].BitLectura,
        BitSupervisa: funciones[i].BitSupervisa,
        ConciliacionId: funciones[i].ConciliacionId,
        UsuarioId: funciones[i].UsuarioId
    })
}
```

Next, properly stringify them

```
var payload = JSON.stringify(func);
```

Then post it as JSON

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'json'
  data: payload,
});
```

Comment: I can't explain why, but now it's working! I was so tired yesterday I probably left some unfinished code from some test, and today I tried again and I works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

Specify `json` [as the dataType](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
$.post(url, { funcionesUsuario: func })
  .done(function (data) {
    alert("good job");
}, 'json');
```

Use `$.ajax` instead: [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: JSON.stringify(func),
  contentType: "application/json",
  type: "POST"
});
```